# Cargar varios combobox al mismo tiempo (WinForms)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una clase para cargar los combobox, hasta ahi bien, me funciona perfectamente pero al querer llenar otros combobox con esta misma clase, simplemente no las carga, anteriormente si lo hacia sin problema, no se que paso

```
public void Cbo(string query, string displayMember, string valueMember, ComboBox ComboBox1)
        {
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conexion))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                    ComboBox1.ValueMember = valueMember;
                    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Esta es mi clase y al momento de cargarlas simplemente carga el primero

```
   private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //llenas los combos
            Combos Cbo = new Combos();
            Cbo.Cbo("SELECT * FROM CATALOGO_FAMILIAS", "Descripcion", "CodigoFamilia", CboFamilia);
            Cbo.Cbo("SELECT ID,DESCRIPCION FROM CATALOGO_FESTEJOS", "DESCRIPCION", "ID", CboFestejo);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aconsejaria intentes invertir la asignacion de las propiedades del combo, recuerdo que habia problemas sino se asigna el DataSource al final

Intenta definiendo

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = displayMember;
ComboBox1.ValueMember = valueMember;
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

primero define el display y value member y luego de estos el DataSource

Ademas no aconsejaria que programes de esta forma, no esta buena, deberias hacerlo mas orientado al negocio

Entonces en la clase Combos defines

```
public static DataTable ObtenerFamilias()
{
    string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
    {
        string query = "SELECT CodigoFamilia, Descripcion FROM CATALOGO_FAMILIAS";
        var SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conexion);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}

public static DataTable ObtenerFestejos()
{
    string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
    {
        string query = "SELECT ID,DESCRIPCION FROM CATALOGO_FESTEJO";
        var SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conexion);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

y luego lo usas

```
private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CboFamilia.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
    CboFamilia.ValueMember = "CodigoFamilia";
    CboFamilia.DataSource = Combos.ObtenerFamilias();
    CboFamilia.SelectedIndex = -1;

    CboFestejo.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPCION";
    CboFestejo.ValueMember = "ID";
    CboFestejo.DataSource = Combos.ObtenerFestejos();
    CboFestejo.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

asi queda muchos mejor, se repite un poco el codigo pero queda clara la separacion entre acceso a datos y la interfaz del usuario

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :) soy algo nuevo pero intento mejorar dia a dia, pero sigue igual, el primero combo si funciona pero ya el segundo no carga nada :/